# how to set kafka connect auto.offset.reset with rest api

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have create a sink kafka connect that convert data to other storage; I want to set `auto.offset.reset` as `latest` when new connector is created with `kafka connect rest api`; I have set `consumer.auto.offset.reset: latest` in configs;

`json
 {
  "name": "test_v14",
  "config": {
    "name": "test_v14",
    "consumer.auto.offset.reset": "latest",
    "connector.class": "...",
    ...
  }
}`

But when task started, kafka consumer still poll records from earliest; So is any other ways to set `auto.offset.reset` as latest;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Prior to Kafka 2.3**

`consumer.auto.offset.reset` needs to be set in the `connect-distributed.properties` file (the Worker).

It cannot be applied to any particular Connector unless that connector class is explicitly creating and loading its own Consumer objects that read in that property.

Comment: Thanks for the response;

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, as of Apache Kafka 2.3.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt but this should be valid for Kafka <2.3. I do not see it being set properly. Any pointers

Comment: @mad_ Make sure you have both the properties listed in Robin's answer. Otherwise, create a new post with your full connector property files

Answer (score 4):

As of Apache Kafka 2.3, it is now possible to set this as part of a connector's configuration.

On the *worker* set:

```
connector.client.config.override.policy=All
```

Then in the connector you can specify

```
"consumer.override.auto.offset.reset": "latest"
```

See this for more details: https://rmoff.net/2019/08/09/starting-a-kafka-connect-sink-connector-at-the-end-of-a-topic/