# KafkaConnect sink set kafka consumer isolation level

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, distributed-transactions

In a standard/custom kafkaconnect sink how can we specify that it should only consume read_comitted messages from kafka topics. I can see the config here but can't see any options (unless it is the default behaviour). Thanks.
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/connect/sink-connect-configs.html

Comment: I am not sure if you want to develop a custom sink or use an existing one. If you're using an existing sink, please tell us more details about which one.

Comment: thx, I want to create a custom sink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override consumer properties (`isolation.level` in your case) for a specific connector, enable client overrides in the worker configuration and then use `consumer.override.*` for a sink connector config:

> `"consumer.override.isolation.level": "read_committed"`

Source: [*Kafka Connect Worker Configuration Properties: Override the Worker Configuration*](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration)

**Note**: Prior to Kafka 2.3 you will need to set it at worker level by adding the line below in worker config

```
consumer.isolation.level=read_committed
```

Please see
[how to set kafka connect auto.offset.reset with rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699970/how-to-set-kafka-connect-auto-offset-reset-with-rest-api)

Comment: Thanks Iskuskov, I tried setting connector.client.config.override.policy=All in worker config and consumer.override.isolation.level=read_committed in sink config. But it still seems to be conusming uncomitted messaes. Also tried adding consumer.override.isolation.level=read_committed in worker config but still no luck.

Comment: I have kafak version < 2.3 ,updated the answer to cater for older version. Works fine now.

Comment: Yes, Connector Client Config Override Policy is available since Kafka 2.3.0. Thanks for updates! If answer is helpful now, please accept it